# Catching error on a merged observable and continue the others in RxJS

Tags: error-handling, merge, rxjs, observable

**Use-case:**
I am trying to implement a save procedure in javascript using RxJS. I have a method named for example set and in it, I want first save the object into the local DB and then also send it to the server. So, for example, I have this code:

```js
set({ obj, group = 'main' }) {
    // tell the LocalDB to store obj in appropriate name and group (appropriate table)
    const storageObservable = this.parealDB.storage.set(this.name, group, { ...obj, status: 0 }); // status 0 means that the records need to be synced (sent) to the server
    // tell the WebClient to sync obj to appropriate name and group (appropriate table)
    const webclientObservable = this.parealDB.webclient.set(this.name, group, obj); // try to send to server and then set status=1 on the localDB / this request should not be failed

    storageObservable.pipe(
        catchError(error => of({
            action: 'STORAGE_ERROR',
            data: error,
        }))
    );

    webclientObservable.pipe(
        tap(result => this.parealDB.storage.set(this.name, group, { _id: obj._id, status: 1 })),
        catchError(error => of({
            action: 'WEBCLIENT_ERROR',
            data: error,
        }))
    );

    return merge(storageObservable, webclientObservable);
}
```

And I want to return a merged observable outside the set method and while catching error of each inner job, also continue the others.

**Problem:**
I have tested this idea with some test observables. First, have a look on the sample:

```js
//emit every 2.5 seconds
const first = interval(200).pipe(
  map(val => "" + val + " A"),
  take(3)
);
//emit every 2 seconds
const second = interval(100).pipe(
  mergeMap(val => {if(val === 1) return throwError('salam'); return of('' + val + " B");}),
  // tap(val => console.log('tapped ', val)),
  take(3)
)
// .pipe(
//   onErrorResumeNext(),
// )

//emit every 1.5 seconds
const third = interval(300).pipe(
  map(val => val + " C"),
  take(3)
);

merge(first, second, third)
// .pipe(
//   catchError(error => of(error)),
// )
.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: console.error,
  complete: () => console.log('completed')
});
```

Now when the second one fails, it brokes the whole job and output is like this:

```
0 B
0 A
salam // (error)
```

And if I try uncommenting the catch error pipe on the merged observable, it will put salam as a normal output and also completing the job but still short-circuiting it:

```
0 B
0 A
salam
completed
```

The best solution I have found is to pipe onErrorResumeNext on each inner observable before merging them together. So uncommenting the mentioned operator on the second observable (which makes the problem) results in this output:

```
0 B
0 A
0 C
1 A
2 A
1 C
2 C
completed
```

It is very near to what I am searching for but out of the set method, I couldn't catch errors (listen on errors)!

**Question:**
So am I miss-using the RxJS observables or is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to happen

Comment: I want this: if for example, B fails, A and C continue publishing with next callback and also the subscriber could be notified of the B's error.

Comment: In RxJS a chain can emit at most one `error` notification and then the chain is disposed. So you can't be notified about two `error`s and then receive `next` with correct data. I think your only option is to turn each `error` into `next` with `catchError()`

Comment: Thanks @martin I have tested this in my first example, I guess this could be a bad practice though.

Comment: Using `catchError` to wrap errors is pretty common in eg. NgRx effects, I think Angular docs is using this as well. Often there's no other way. Maybe you could make multiple subscriptions with intermediate Subject for each input but that would be unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the stream alive but using repeat() operator, but use it with care, you have to make sure the source stream is an hot observable or you may run into infinite looping.

```
streamA.pipe(
catch(e=>of(e)),
repeat())
```

Comment: Nice tip @FanCheung but this is not relevant to my problem. If I catch error on one of the streams, then the error will not propagate to the merged stream and if do that on the merged stream, it will break-down after catching the error.

Comment: You can use the same pattern for merge stream, think of it as a failed resubscrition

Comment: I do not agree with you in this case. Because the job of each sub-stream runs independently and while the merged stream is throwing an error of one failed stream, the other streams are still alive (and I don't want and in some cases can't kill them) while the merged stream stops immediately.

Comment: What is you want to achieve ? You can even consider using repeatwhen operator if that’s what u worried about